# How to improve multiple StringReplace calls?

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-xe7

I read files from customers and I need to process the read data and remove some unneeded characters. My function works, but I'm trying to improve the FixData function to improve speed/performance and maintainability.

**Is it possible to replace multiple StringReplace calls with something that will only loop through data once and replace with whatever it needs to?**

I can't find MultipleStringReplace or similar function.

MCVE:

```
function FixData(const vStr:string):string;
var i:integer;
begin
  Result:=vStr;

  // empty string
  if Result = #0 then Result := '';

  // fix just New line indicator
  if Result = #13#10 then  Result := #8;

  // remove 'end'/#0  characters
    if Pos(#0, Result) > 0 then
      for i := 1 to Length(Result) do
        if Result[i] = #0 then
          Result[i] := ' ';

    //  #$D#$A  -> #8
    if Pos(#$D#$A, Result) > 0 then
      Result := StringReplace(Result, #$D#$A, #8, [rfReplaceAll]);

    // remove &#xD
    if Pos('&#xD;', Result) > 0 then
      Result := StringReplace(Result, '&#xD;', '', [rfReplaceAll]);

    // #$A -> #8
    if Pos(#$A, Result) > 0 then
      Result := StringReplace(Result, #$A, #8, [rfReplaceAll]);

    // replace " with temp_replacement value
    if Pos(chr(34), Result) > 0 then
      Result := StringReplace(Result, chr(34), '\_/', [rfReplaceAll]);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var vStr,vFixedStr:string;
begin
  vStr:='testingmystr:"quotest" - '+#0+' substr &#xD; new line '#$A' 2nd line '#$D#$A' end of data';
  vFixedStr:=FixData(vStr);
end;
```

Comment: *Is it possible to replace multiple StringReplace calls with something that will only loop through data once and replace with whatever it needs to?* Yes it is. What is stopping you from doing just that? Allocate an output string. Loop through the input string copying characters into the output string. If you detect a character that needs to be replaced, replace it.

Comment: maybe using regex is a better option?

Comment: @daryal, he mentioned "speed/performance and maintainability"...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hm, didn't think of that. I had an idea of looping through an array of searched values and call StringReplace, but this would be the same thing as I'mdoing now, just different.. So,  you suggest to loop through data string char by char and check each character if needs replacement, right? Makes sense.

Comment: Yes. You'll need to be cute when you replace two characters with one, but you can do it all in one pass.

Comment: @daryal In my experience with RegEx it's not really performance friendly on large strings or lots of executions, so I'm avoiding it. I only use it for one time call - before displaying string to the user,where speed is not important.

Comment: I believe the fist step would be to remove all the `If Pos(...) > 0 then ` - because `StringReplace` already does it and thus those checks give nothing but a redundant extra scanning of the string.

Comment: interesting, I thought for Delphi there would be easy to find a code that splits the string upon multiple string delimiters. It is not. All the splitters I met either use single string delimiter or a number of one-char delimiters, nothing else....

Comment: A compiled regex can be very efficient

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Would you care to point to a resource where i can get more info about 'compiled' regex? i don't understand what that means... search doesn't provide anything, either.

Comment: websearch yields hits for me

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OK, thank you.

Comment: @MikeTorrettinni the worst part of ReplaceStr is that when the sizes of new and old [atterns are dfferent, then the expensive memory copy is to be done. Actually that is nothing new, that is a textbook property of any array-like container: random access and replacement Is very cheap, but inserting/removing elements is very expensive. So that is usually the first performance optimization - do as few memory copying as you can while keeping code readable. Actually in my snippet I could avoid copying chunks of strings but instead yield "coordinates" of chunks to be copied later in one pass.

Comment: That would provide for pre-allocating the exact amount of memory and making one memory copy of `InputString` data less. But that would make the code yet harder for you to grasp. Most per-performance optimizations are fusing different logical stages into same execution units, thus blurring the logic structure and making maintenance harder. On the opposite, I could separate stages w/o overlapping and the code would be cleaner to understand conceptually, but would be less optimized in execution. You said  "speed/performance and maintainability" but often that is a trade-off, an either-or not and

Comment: _but instead yield "coordinates" of chunks to be copied later in one pass_  Oh, actually that is exactly what you can see in the function provided by SamZ, except that it uses somewhat inefficient dynamic array to collect those coordinates.

Comment: @Arioch'The I was afraid it would be something as complex as you describe it. I'm testing SamZ, but first tests are not so encouraging, I guess it's about the variety of my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, you have to split your string into a set of strings ( non-delimiters and delimiters(patterns) ) and then replace items in the array and then combine them back yet again. You would start with longer patterns and go to shorter ones (safety check against pattern-inside-pattern), then an extra run would be to make one-char-to-one-char substitutions (as they can be done in-place and would not require memory copying).

Double copy, and search scaling as O(Length(input)*Count(Delimiters)).

Something like this pseudocode draft (not implemented to the last dot, just for you to have the idea):

*Since your patterns are short I think linear search would be okay, otherwise more optimized but complex algorithms would be needed:* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Algorithms_using_a_finite_set_of_patterns

Hash it to smaller functions as you see fit for ease of understanding/maintenance.

```
Type TReplaceItem = record (match, subst: string; position: integer);
var matches: array of TReplaceItem;

SetLength(matches, 3);
matches[0].match := '&#xD;'; // most long first;
  matches[0].subst := ''; 
matches[1].match := #$D#$A; // most long first;
  matches[1].subst := #8; 
matches[2].match := #34; // most long first;
  matches[2].subst := '\_/'; 

sb := TStringBuilder.Create( 2*Length(InputString) ); 
// or TList<String>, or iJclStringList of Jedi CodeLib, or TStringList... depending on performance and preferences
// Capacity parameter is for - warming up, pre-allocating memory that is "usually enough" 
try    

  NextLetterToParse := 1;
  for I := Low(matches) to high(matches) do
    matches[I].position := PosEx(matches[I].match, InputString, NextLetterToParse ); 

  While True do begin

     ClosestMatchIdx := -1;

     ClosestMatchPos := { minimal match[???].Position that is >= NextLetterToParse };
     ClosestMatchIdx := {index - that very [???] above - of the minimum, IF ANY, or remains -1}

     if ClosestMatchIdx < 0 {we have no more matches} then begin

      //dump ALL the remaining not-yet-parsed rest
        SB.Append( Copy( InputString, NextLetterToParse , Length(InputString));

      // exit stage1: splitting loop
        break;
     end;

     // dumping the before-any-next-delimiter part of not-parsed-yet tail of the input
     // there may be none - delimiters could go one after another
     if ClosestMatchPos > NextLetterToParse then
         SB.Append( Copy( InputString, NextLetterToParse, ClosestMatchPos-NextLetterToParse);

     // dumping the instead-of-delimiter pattern
     SB.Append( matches[ ClosestMatchIdx ].Subst );

     ShiftLength := (ClosestMatchPos - NextLetterToParse) + Length(matches[ ClosestMatchIdx ].Match); 
     // that extra part got already dumped now

     Inc( NextLetterToParse, ShiftLength);

     for I := Low(matches) to high(matches) do
       if matches[I].position < NextLetterToParse then
          matches[I].position := PosEx(matches[I].match, InputString, NextLetterToParse ); 
     // updating next closest positions for every affected delimiter,
     // those that were a bit too far to be affected ( usually all 
     // but the one being dumped) need not to be re-scanned 

  end; // next stage 1 loop iteration
```

Now we have a container/array/list/anything comprised of non-matched chunks and replaced patterns. Except for in-place one-char replacement. Time to merge and do one last scan.

```
Stage2String := SB.ToString();

finally 
  SB.Destroy; 
end;

for I := 1 to Length( Stage2String ) do
  case Stage2String[I] of
    #0: Stage2String[I] := #32;

    #10, #13: Stage2String[I] := #8;
    // BTW - ^M=#13=#$D sometimes can be met without trailing ^J=#10=#$A
    // that was the end-of-line char used in old Macintosh text files

    else ; // do nothing, let it stay as is
  end;

Result := Stage2String;
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort @Arioch 'The, but this is proving to be too complex for me, I didn't know what I'm getting myself into. So, the Sam z proved to be suitable for me.

Comment: SAM Z function is even more complex, it "unrolls" the stage that I skipped for the sake of clarity :-) I suggest you to read something about Functional Languages, that are higher-abstractions languages than Delphi/C++/Java and tend to imagine process as the data and a pipeline of transformations (functions). Just to make you more flexible. Or perhaps to reflex upon `Pipeline` pattern from OmniThreads Delphi library. "When you only have hammer you only see nails everywhere". This code is absolutely not complex, it is just from a bit different perspective

Comment: Basically, if we sat around one desk, with paper and pencil, I could show you the chunks moving and those concepts without low-level details, all those multiple variables, and you would see how simple it is... That is one more reason why I suggest you to read some basic intros into FP language, you see leaves not branches in my code, you see implementation not the very simple idea... And it seems complex, when it is absolutely not.... Pity.

Comment: By complex, I'm not sure how to fill in the missing parts.

Comment: The only missing part is finding a minimum in the array - what is complex in that ???? o_O

Comment: I assume `SB:TStringBuilder; ... SB.Add -> SB.Append` and `SB.Dispose -> SB.DisposeOf`, correct?

Comment: almost, SB.Dispose -> `SB.Destroy / SB.Free / FreeAndNil(SB)` in Delphi for Windows
In Delphi/LLVM you can just `SB:=nil;` or exit of the proceudure where SB is a local var.

Comment: Great, now it compiles. Moving forward with testing.