# Delphi remove symbols from String

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have searched and tried a couple of loops which are supposed to remove symbols from a string, I need this because certain locations can have a "/" or other type of symbol and I need it removed since FTP will think it's a folder, and I need the string in a name.

The String 'place' varies from the persons current working location, for example there's a 'place' = "S/A StorageRoom", the '/' part of the String make's FTP think that it's a subfolder.

For now I'm using this, which I think is pretty large and could use 'shortening':

```
   place := StringReplace(place, ',', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, '.', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, '/', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, '!', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, '@', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, '#', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, '$', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, '%', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, '^', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, '&', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, '*', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, '''', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, '"', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, ';', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, '_', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, '(', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, ')', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, ':', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, '|', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, '[', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, ']', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
   place := StringReplace(place, '\', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

Edit:
I'm currently using RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin

Comment: What Delphi version are you using? Recent versions can do this more easily than older ones, so it is relevant. Please add  a tag for the specific Delphi version (7, 2007, etc.).

Comment: Added in the text, currently I'm using RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin

Comment: I added the tag for you. Can you [edit] your post to provide a sample of the string that would be in `place`? You can do this pretty easily with a regular expression, but the specific one you will need will depend on the text you're actually working with, so samples would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to improve multiple StringReplace calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34769953/how-to-improve-multiple-stringreplace-calls)

Comment: @KenWhite I added an example

Comment: How comfortable are you using RegEx? [TRegEx.Replace](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx.Replace)  should work with [\\\/,.!@#$%^&"';_():|\[\]]+

Comment: @S.Langhammer I have never heard of TRegEx.Replace, I'll check upon it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a quest to avoid unnecessary heap allocations, here is a variant of @Ancaron's answer that only does one allocation and a final size reduction in order to produce the answer.

The trick is to preallocate the resulting string at the beginning, and then fill it up with accepted characters.
At the end, adjust the resulting string length.

```
program TestStripChars;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

function StripChars (const Text : string; const InValidChars : SysUtils.TSysCharSet) : string;
var
  i,j : Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result,Length(Text));  // Preallocate result maximum length
  j := 0;  // Resulting string length counter
  for i := 1 to Length(Text) do begin
    if not CharInSet(Text[i],InValidChars) then begin
      Inc(j);
      Result[j] := Text[i];
    end;
  end;
  SetLength(Result,j); // Set result actual length
end;

var
  place : String;
begin
  place := 'Hell$$o D.,e.$lphi';
  place := StripChars(place,[',','.','$']);
  WriteLn(place);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

---

From a comment it looks like the OP is using a compiler setting with zero based string handling.

Here is a function that handles both scenarios:

```
function StripChars ( const Text : string; const InValidChars : SysUtils.TSysCharSet) : string;
var
  i,j,zbsAdj : Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result,Length(Text));  // Preallocate result maximum length
  j := 0; // Resulting string length counter
  zbsAdj := 1-Low(String); // Handles zero based string offset
  for i := Low(Text) to High(Text) do begin
    if not CharInSet(Text[i],InValidChars) then begin
      Inc(j);
      Result[j-zbsAdj] := Text[i];
    end;
  end;
  SetLength(Result,j); // Set result actual length
end;
```

Comment: I had a weird thing happen with the code, so basically I put the function in my source, called the 'StripChars' with all of the characters I want removed, I aswell used my test string "S/A StorageRoom", what happened was that at first it would be output like this "A StorageRoom" and would sometimes get a weird chinese or some other letter in the place of "S", I thought I would start the for loop not from 1 but from 0, that fixed the "SA StorageRoom" the "S" problem, but now ftp would say invalid character and would stop the transfer, any ideas?

Comment: Forgot to mention that the Weird symbol would happen for like 8/10 times and other times it would work it would look like something like this "漢S StorageRoom" or something else in the "漢" spot.

Comment: See my update. You are most likely using a compiler with `{$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS ON}`. My edit will handle that for you.

Comment: FWIW, how much faster is your "reduced allocation" version? Did you check that?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, 32-bit compiler -> 4-5 times faster, 64-bit compiler 6-7 times faster. The test was using the OP's test string. I know that Delphi's strings are fast for concatenation, thanks to COW and FastMM memory manager. But it still pays to take attention to avoid hitting the heap when possible. How much this really is worth in a real application, would depend on the application.

Comment: @LURD: OK, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You cold just use a function like

```
function StripChars ( const Text : string; InValidChars : TSetOfChar ) : string;
var
  S : string;
  i : integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  if Length(Text) > 0 then
  begin
    S := '';
    for i := 1 to length ( Text ) do
      if not CharInSet(Text[i],InValidChars) then  
        S := S + Text [ i ];
    Result := S;
  end;
end;
```

and then only call

```
place := StripChars(place,[',','.', and so on]);
```

Comment: Ugh, quite a lot of copying and reallocation here. It is possible to do with max 2 calls to `SetLength`

Comment: IME, the memory manager copes very well with scenarios like repeated `S := S + SomeChar`. Not that much reallocation at all, although one would expect it. That is why StringBuilders are seldom needed.